# How to select an element with CDATA without child elements

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

In an XML file I have an element `<WPG>` containing `A lot of text`, including a child with some more text.

```
<WPG><![CDATA[A lot of text]]>
  <WPL>
    <ADD><profile ref="994042" />
      <Rem><![CDATA[Some more text]]></Rem>
    </ADD>
  </WPL>
</WPG>
```

When I use

```
<xsl:value-of select="WPG"/>
```

I get `A lot of text` including `Some more text`.

How can I get only `A lot of text` without `Some more text` without changing the XML files itself?

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:value-of select="WPG/text()"/>
```

will work for your example - not sure if it's general enough to cover all your cases, though.

Comment: Could also normalize the whitespace `<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(WPG/text())"/>`

Comment: @DanielHaley I don't know about that: perhaps the whitespace inside the payload is significant?

Comment: Perhaps; that's why I said "could". I figured if the OP saw your answer (+1) and my comment, they could probably figure it out for themselves.

Comment: @DanielHaley No argument, just noting.